# How do I add two questionmarks and a whitespace to my RegEx?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How do I add a whitespace and two questionmarks '??' to this RegEx `/51|02|52/`. 
I have tried a number of ways but nothing's working.

Here is the rest of the code, so you can get a clear picture of what I'm attempting to do:

```
$('.numeric-year').keyup(function () {
    var theseNumbers = /51|02|52/;
    $(this).toggleClass('field-error', !theseNumbers.test(this.value));
});
```

I've tried adding `\s` for the whitespace to the RegEx but it hasnt worked. I've also tried adding `|??` for the two questionmarks yet again no success

Would really appreciate some help with this one, Thanks

Comment: Could you explain what yo want the regex to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean "add to"? Can you give some example strings that you want to be matched, but aren't at the moment?

Comment: @EdoDodo OK I have determined that I dont need the questionmarks anymore...all I need is to add a 'find a whitespace' to the RegEx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `?` is a special character, namely the quantifier '0 or 1'. You'd need to escape it.

As for whitespace, use `+` quantifier, meaning '1 or more'.

```
/51|02|52|\?\?|\s+/
```

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, that's "0 or 1 occurrence of the previous entity", not "the character 0 or the character 1".

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to escape those question marks:

```
var theseNumbers = /51|02|52|\?\?/;
```